can a company complain to the police to a freelancer without any agreement for IP agreement dispute
I got an Email from a HR by sanctioned a copy typing work. for this I paid ₹300/-INR . But I thought that it was fake so I asked for money. but he didn't gave me money and didn't replied to me. Then I got another email by sanctioned work from another name but I never sighn up that platform. Now I got an another email from Delhi police , that,(Alert!
A police complaint against the user has been received by Delhi Police. A complaint has been registered for bringing loss of money to company under the name of milestone creation worth Rs. 4260 and not responding to IP agreement dispute of Rs. 1790. Complain will be registered under IPC section 420 (cheating and dishonesty acquiring someone property), section 500 (defamation of the employer). Few IPC sections will be implied which falls under cognisable, non compound and non bailable offense. Solve the dispute within 24 hours. Otherwise, a FIR will be registered). I didn't sighn any agreement or contact. what will do I next?

Remember, people who want to scam you can send emails supposedly from authorities. Get the correct number of the police and contact them to find out if this is real.

If you never received any money, and never provided any work, it is clearly just a scam. Ignore it. The fact that you don't know this, scares me for you.

This is a scam, full stop.
Cease communication with this supposed company, and move on.
